# How to properly link basic calculator results to buttons? (failing to do so)

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, this week was our second lesson that came with an assignment. Disclaimer: I have a learning disability so sorry ifgot the solution is really obvious.

Alright so in the first lesson we have to create a basic calculator with input fields, this went great, followed along with the teacher and thought I understood it. - Second lesson was making the calculator work with buttons instead.

This is what I came up with:

```js
function insert(num) {
  document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value + num
}

var result = document.getElementById('result');

result.addEventListener('click', function(number1, number2) {
  var a = number1;
  var b = number2;
  var op = (document.querySelector("#operator").value);
  var calculate;

  if (op == "add") {
    calculate = a + b;
  } else if (op == "min") {
    calculate = a - b;
  } else if (op == "divi") {
    calculate = a / b;
  } else if (op == "mul") {
    calculate = a * b;
  }


});
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" name="textview">
</form>
<div id="operator">
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert(7)">7</button>
  <button onclick="insert(8)">8</button>
  <button onclick="insert(9)">9</button>
  <button onclick="insert('/')" id="divi"> / </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert(4)">4</button>
  <button onclick="insert(5)">5</button>
  <button onclick="insert(6)">6</button>
  <button onclick="insert('*')" id="mul"> * </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert(1)">1</button>
  <button onclick="insert(2)">2</button>
  <button onclick="insert(3)">3</button>
  <button onclick="insert('-')" id="min"> - </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert('C')"> C </button>
  <button onclick="insert(0)"> 0 </button>
  <button onclick="insert('')" id="result"> = </button>
  <button onclick="insert('+')" id="add"> + </button>
</div>
```

Result: All buttons work and input the numbers but it seems to not connect with my function.

First I checked console log for errors but it doesn't give any. Then I asked my teachers and he said we're only allowed to use what we learned in the first 2 lessons, so i'm trying to stick with it but really have no clue what I did wrong here. Any help would be appreciated very muchthanks all!

Comment: Now the answer depends on what you learned in your 1st two lessons. For starter `#operator` is a div and it does not have a value so `var op = (document.querySelector("#operator").value);` will always be undefined and so the calculation will never happen.

Comment: @Manish sorry if it sounded vague. i'm allowed to use any answer after i failed, which is now. as long as it stays within this context and i understand it. i removed .value now. are there any other big errors? thanks!

Comment: I'll give you a hint read the value from input. and check which operator is present using `indexOf` function and then `split` and `parseInt` and do the math. and store in the variable.

Comment: @Want2learn123 reverted the question to its initial state.. So that someone else seeking similar kind of help can benefit from this.. Easier to find the question.. And on stack overflow its all about helping so we do not remove the original questions :). Happy learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code that can solve your problem. What is happening in this is.

1. Whenever you select anything from the keys check if its not a number using `isNaN()`
2. If its is not a number the add a space after and before it when inserting into the textbox

   `document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value + ' ' + num + ' ';`
3. When the result button (=) is clicked get the value of the textbox

   `var operands = equation.split(' ');`
4. Now you will have an array (`operands`) of 3 items which will have first item as the first number, second item as the operation and the third item as the second number.

Now you can operate accordingly. Below is a working snippet for the above solutions.

```js
function insert(num) {
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value + ' ' + num + ' '; // add a space after and before the operator
  } else {
    document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value + num;
  }

}

var result = document.getElementById('result');

result.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var equation = document.getElementById('equation').value;
  var operands = equation.split(' '); // split the string by space which give you and array of 3 elements
  var op = operands[1];
  var a = operands[0];
  var b = operands[2];
  var calculate;
  if (op == "+") {
    calculate = a + b;
  } else if (op == "-") {
    calculate = a - b;
  } else if (op == "/") {
    calculate = a / b;
  } else if (op == "*") {
    calculate = a * b;
  }

  console.log('Result is: ' + calculate);
});
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" id="equation" name="textview">
</form>
<div id="operator">
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert(7)">7</button>
  <button onclick="insert(8)">8</button>
  <button onclick="insert(9)">9</button>
  <button onclick="insert('/')" id="divi"> / </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert(4)">4</button>
  <button onclick="insert(5)">5</button>
  <button onclick="insert(6)">6</button>
  <button onclick="insert('*')" id="mul"> * </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert(1)">1</button>
  <button onclick="insert(2)">2</button>
  <button onclick="insert(3)">3</button>
  <button onclick="insert('-')" id="min"> - </button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="insert('C')"> C </button>
  <button onclick="insert(0)"> 0 </button>
  <button onclick="insert('')" id="result"> = </button>
  <button onclick="insert('+')" id="add"> + </button>
</div>
```

Read more about

- [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

There can be many more solutions to this using different ways. Try and explore. Good luck with your learning.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution!!! I will study your answer so I 100% understand and learn from it, thanks again!!

Comment: Alright, sorry for deleting. 1 final question: I studied .split() and .isNaN() and understand them now. Is it required or/and the easiest way to create an array for the fields? (var a/b/op in this case)

Comment: Yes in this case yes this is the simplest given the conditions. As i said there can be different solutions but those depend.. For instance you can have three different textboxes and add your operands and operator separately.. And as you learn along you may even find a simpler one but they will need knowledge of some other concepts of javascript..